# XCode, Swift: Expressions are not allowed at the top level

Tags: swift, xcode

```
import UIKit

class MarksStruct {
    var mark: Int
    init(mark: Int) {
        self.mark = mark
    }
}

class studentMarks {
    var mark = 300
}

let marks = studentMarks()
print("Mark is \(marks.mark)")  //Expressions are not allowed at the top level
```

Anyone know why I get the error on the last line `"Expressions are not allowed at the top level"` and how do I fix it?

Comment: @Valysar your code should be inside a method of your view controller

Answer (score 4):

Your code will work in the playground, but it can not work in a normal project.
Move this code to a separate function and call it when needed.

```
let marks = studentMarks()
print("Mark is \(marks.mark)")
```